# How to add a right click function on a program?

Tags: bash, nautilus, games

I have built a game from source, and at the same time, I made an updater to the game written in a .sh extension. ti launch the update program you need to open the terminal and type bash ./updater-name.sh. this uses a lot of time and is not cool to use.

I thought of making the program executable through a right-click on the game. I want to add a function. on this program only, and so it executes the .sh file.

I know you can use the file manager-actions/nautilus, but I didn't find any way to add a function to a specific program.

maybe somoeone could help about that?

Comment: I am not exactly shure what you want but if its right click on a program/file within nautilus and than add the entry "Update program", you can try something: 
`[Desktop Entry]
    Actions=ShrinkPDF
    Icon=transform-crop-resize
    MimeType=application/x-pdf
    ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
    Type=Service
    X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel

    [Desktop Action Update]
    Exec= /bin/bash /path/to/your/script %f    
    Name=Update` 
In KDE place the file in ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/ ...unfortunatley I don't know where the desktop entries are in Gnome....

Comment: Check out the right mime-type of your programs...

Comment: I will try that! I meant like, you can add costume functions for example on the right-click in the file manager. But if you could add it to an installed program/game. You go to the program list, right-click on the game and between the things you can do (info, Mark as favorite and the others) you could add a new button called update, that will launch the update code